# Embed remote video in Nuxt v3 + Vuetify app

Tags: vue.js, iframe, nuxt.js, html5-video

I have a Nuxt v3 + Vuetify app and want to embed a couple of video in my pages. One is from Youtube, another from Dailymotion and another from Invidious!

I'm currently using an `<iframe>`, but I'm looking for alternatives because I cannot use iframe anymore.

What do you suggest?
I tried to search online and found only pretty old libraries and most of them support only specific providers (Youtube, Vimeo etc...).

Thanks